# How to cumulative update Windows SP1 fresh installation in Virtual Box to the latest update till Jan 2020

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, windows-update

I sometimes work with Windows 7 in Virtual Box and install it using SP1 ISO. Now my goal is to install all updates till the end of support using an offline and fast method.

How do I achieve this?

Update:

My preference for methods are:

1. Official ISO
2. MSU installers (split into any number of packages as long as they don't take hours to finish)
3. Unofficial/Custom ISO/Virtual Box Image

Comment: Do you want to slipstream the updates [into your ISO](https://www.howtogeek.com/255540/the-last-windows-7-iso-youll-ever-need-how-to-slipstream-the-convenience-rollup/) or do you want to update the VirtualBox image?

Comment: @lx07 The Most preferred method is Official ISO, then MSU installer, then unofficial/custom ISO and least preferred method is Virtual Box image.

Comment: There is no fast method but you can use this software to build an updater dvd that automates the update process>>>>>>>https://download.wsusoffline.net/

Answer (score 1):

I have a Windows 7 Pro machine using VMware.  Just run Windows Updates. It is still updating what can be updated. No Feature updates, but security and Office updates still update and install.

If you are building multiple machines (why?) then you would need to add the updates to your image, but you can still do this.